# Output manipulation for nslookup

Tags: cmd, output, nslookup

I've got a small nslookup .cmd, that gives me more output than needed.
I already know the names of the machines I'm looking for, as well as the DNS name, the only Information I need is the machines address.

```
@echo off

set variable=1

:start
nslookup ***-%variable%.****** >> test.txt
set /a variable=variable+1

timeout /t 3

if %variable% LSS *** goto start

:next
```

This is what I get in my .txt file if the nslookup did find a machine:

> Server: **********
>
> Address: ***.***.***.***
>
> Name: ****.****.****
>
> Address: ***.***.***.***

But if it didnt find a machine i still get:

> Server: **********
>
> Address: ***.***.***.***

Could the output be manipulated that way, that it only writes to the .txt when it actually finds a machine and only takes the address part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't mind executing `nslookup` twice per server (one time to check, if server exists, second to get the output):

```
nslookup ***-%variable%.****** 2>nul|findstr /b "Name:">nul && nslookup ***-%variable%.****** >> test.txt
```